# Array of structures as parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a structure defined like that :

```
struct lTransitions {
    char c;
    int etatSuivant;
    struct lTransitions *next;
};
```

I create an array of structures :

```
struct lTransitions *automate[NBETATS];
```

(with NBETATS = 100)
Each index contains a pointer to a variable based on my structure. As you can see, I have a "next" pointer in my structure. It allows me to create a chain, so the next element is linked to the current one by this pointer.
I'm calling a function to fill it :

```
void lireFichier(struct lTransitions **automate, int *etatInitial, int *etatFinal);
```

by doing :

```
lireFichier(automate, &etatInitial, &etatFinal)
```

(with etatInital and etatFinal two ints)

This function only creates transitions (variables based on my structure), and calls an other one to add the new transition to my array. This other function is the following one :

```
void ajouterTransition(struct lTransitions **automate, int e1, struct lTransitions *t)
{
    if(automate[e1] == NULL)
    {
        t->next = NULL;
        automate[e1] = t;
    }
    else{
        t->next = automate[e1];
        automate[e1] = t;
    }
}
```

At the end of ajouterTransition(), if I check the value of t->c, I have the character I'm looking for. Same after calling ajouterTransition(). (So if I check inside ajouterTransition() or inside lireFichier(), I have the good character). Now, if I check from my main function (after calling lireFichier()), I have a strange character, not the one I'm looking for.
Where am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT :** Here is the code for lireFichier() :

```
void lireFichier(struct lTransitions **automate, int *etatInitial, int *etatFinal)
{
    FILE *f = NULL; // représente un fichier en C
    int e1, e2 ; // e1 etat initial d'une transition et e2 état final d'une transition
    char c; // caractère d'une transition
    char tab[TAILLETAB]; // Chaîne de caractères qui nous servira pour la lecture ligne par ligne du fichier (~buffer de lecture)
    struct lTransitions *t = NULL; // Pointeur vers une transition

    // Ouverture du du fichier
    f = fopen("automate.txt", "r");

    // Vérifier si le fichier a bien été ouvert. Sinon, envoyer une erreur et sortir du programme
    if (!f)
    {
       printf("Le fichier automate.txt n'a pas pu être lu !");
       fclose(f);
       exit(1);
    }

    // TODO - Lecture de la première ligne - l'état initial
    fgets(tab, TAILLETAB, f);
    tab[0] = tab[1];
    tab[1] = '\0';
    *etatInitial = atoi(tab);

    // TODO - Lecture de la deuxième ligne - l'état final - On considère qu'il y a un seul état final pour notre exemple
    fgets(tab, TAILLETAB, f);
    tab[0] = tab[1];
    tab[1] = '\0';
    *etatFinal = atoi(tab);

    // Lecture de toutes les transitions de l'automate - Lit ligne par ligne jusqu'à la fin du fichier
    while (fgets(tab, TAILLETAB, f) != NULL)
    {
        // TODO - Récupérer dans les variables e1, c et e2 les valeurs lues dans le fichier et qui ont été stockées dans tab à l'aide de la fonction sscanf()
        sscanf(tab, "%d;%c;%d", &e1, &c, &e2);

        // TODO - Créer une transition avec c et e2 (faire appel à des fonctions déjà définies dans ce même fichier)
        t = creerTransition(c, e2);

        // TODO - Ajouter la transition créée dans l'automate en utilisant e1 comme indice du tableau 'automate' (faire appel à des fonctions déjà définies dans ce même fichier)
        ajouterTransition(automate, e1, t);
    }

    // Fermer le fichier
    fclose(f);
}
```

Because all the comments are in french, here is a little explanation :
- I open my file where the transitions are written (format : "first_state(int);character;second_state(int)" (for exemple : "1;:;2" means that if I'm at state 1 and the current character is ':' then I go to state 2)
- The two first lines follows a different format : "#state(int)" (for exemple "#0"), so I read them separate from the rest)
- Then I have my loop, in which I read the rest of the file line by line. I create my transition using creerTransition(), then I add it to my array using ajouterTransition()

**EDIT 2 :** Everything in the code shown works perfectly, I just made a mistake in an other function..!

Comment: I think we really need to see them implementation of `lireFichier()`

Comment: I added the code and a little explanation

Comment: You in fact have array of pointers to your structure.

Comment: My bad, everything was working, the mistake was during the creation of the transition..!

Comment: "I create an array of structures" - that's an array of pointers to structures (i.e., no actual instances of this structure are instantiated).

Comment: You're right @goodvibration , oops !